# How do I "clean" ghost Windows Store apps from Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

I am trying to run the Windows App Cert Kit (Edit: **on my local machine**)and am getting two entries for one of my apps. This could be because of something I did a while ago - however - I cant figure out how to uninstall that other app.

When I type the name of the app on the start screen, I get just one item listed (which is the kosher app, not the ghost app)

Where is information about such apps kept and how do I "clean" it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PowerShell to manage your apps! Try this:

```
Get-Command -module appx /* gets the commands you can use to manipulate win8 apps */
Get-AppxPackage * | ft name /* lists the names of all apps installed on the machine */
Remove-AppxPackage 'NameOfApp' /* removes the app */
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only place in which you can edit these kind of information is **Dashboard** in Microsoft Dev-Center, available [here](https://appdev.microsoft.com/StorePortals/en-us).

Probably, the correct app is a "published app" while the ghost app is a "in development app".

Comment: Added a clarification - this is running on my local machine.